# Initialization of malloc & calloc

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

Why does `malloc` always initialize with garbage values and `calloc` always intialize with 0? Any reason behind it?

Why can't we use `realloc` instead of `malloc` for dynamic memory allocation?

After reallocating memory dynamically, what are initial values of it?

Code:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,50);
printf("%d",*ptr);
```

Comment: The code as presented will invoke *undefined behavior*. `ptr` has no determinate value prior to being passed to `realloc`, which requires one of (a) the value  of `NULL`, or (b) the result of a `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, or any derivative utilizing one of the above (ex: `strdup`, `getline`, etc.). That said, you *can* use `realloc` to replace `malloc` and `calloc`, if managed correctly. It is often an academic task given to up-and-coming C engineers to attempt to implement their own `malloc` and `calloc` using only `realloc` to do so. ex: `malloc(n)` == `realloc(NULL, n)`

Comment: Also worth noting, `printf("%d",*ptr);` also invokes *undefined behavior*. There is no determinate value set at `*ptr` prior to encountering that statement (at least none in the posted code). Finally (seriously, done after this), [don't cast memory allocation library function results in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 3):

[`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) is made to just allocate memory of the specified size. [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) does the same (with different parameters), but is also designed to zero initialize the memory. It is just how they are designed.

You can use [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) for dynamic reallocation, but it is used to reallocate, which in your example it is not. `realloc` can only be used on memory already initialized with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, or if the pointer is `NULL` then it is equivalent to `malloc`

Answer (score 3):

> *Why does Malloc always initialize with Garbage values & Calloc always intialize with 0?*

This behaviour is defined by the C standard.

In fact `malloc()` does not initialise the memory allocated at all. This mostly is for performance reasons. Do not read it, before having written to it yourself, to not provoke UB.

`calloc()` *is* specified to initialise the memory allocated to all `0`s.

> *why can't we use realloc instead of malloc for dynamic memeory allocation.*

[You can](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p3). Just pass `NULL` as 1st parameter.

Your example adjusted:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
ptr = realloc(ptr, 50);
*ptr = 42;
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

prints:

```
42
```